# Laravel count values from collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

How to get the sum of the multiplication of this data.

Here is my **kvit** table

```
id | hamkor_id | oper_type 
1  |  10       |     20
```

Here is **operation** table

```
id | kvit_id | product_id | store_id| amount | price 
1  |     1   |     5      |    1    |    10  |   15
2  |     1   |     6      |    1    |    5   |   10
```

Here is relationships

```
class Kvit extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

public function operation(){
    return $this->hasMany(Operation::class);
}

public function hamkor(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'hamkor_id','id');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function store(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
 }
}
```

Here is controller

```
$user = Auth::id();
    $datas = Kvit::with('user', 'hamkor', 'store', 'operation')->where('user_id', $user)->get();
    return view('operations.index', compact('datas'));
```

Here is my view

```
    <table class="datatables-basic table" id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Hamkor</th>
        <th>Store</th>
        <th>Summ</th>
        <th>Amallar</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $idx => $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$idx+1}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{$data->date}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->hamkor->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->store->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ **here i want to get result(200)** }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-flat-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    Edit
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-flat-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-view"></i>
                    View
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-flat-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

I need to get the total amount by multiplying the amount per product by the price.
That is the total amount of the receipt
Like this (10*15 + 5*10) = 200
How can it possible?

Comment: I do not understand your question fully. Perhaps you can specify what model and what columns should be multiplied by each other in your original question?

Comment: here is formula 
```sum (amount * price) group by kvit_id = 1```

Comment: I have added an answer, hopefully it solves your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate the `sum` of the `amount` * `price` column in the `Operation` table, grouped by `kvit_id`?

You can solve this by adding a [custom attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to your `Kvit` model.

```
// Kvit model
class Kvit extends Model
{
    public function getTotalPriceAttribute(): float
    {
        return $this->operation->sum( function($operation) {
            return $operation->amount * $operation->price;
        });
    }
}
```

In your Blade view you can simply call:

```
{{ $data->kvit->total_price }}
```

This is one way to solve your question.

**A couple of remarks:**

1. Shouldn't `operation` be pluralized since it is a `HasMany` relation? (`operations`)?
2. I have used `float` as return type, this could however be an integer and depends on your implementation.
3. You could remove `$idx =>` from your `foreach`. Instead, you could use the [Loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) and call `{{ $loop->iteration }}` instead of `{{ $idx + 1 }}`

**Full example:**

```
class Operation
{
    public $amount;
    public $price;

  
    public function __construct($amount, $price)
    {
      $this->amount = $amount;
      $this->price = $price;
    }
}

class Kvit
{
    public $operations;
  
    public function __construct($operations)
    {
      $this->operations = $operations; 
    }
  
    public function calculate(): float
    {
        return $this->operations->sum( function($operation) {
            return $operation->amount * $operation->price;
        }); 
    }
}

$operation1 = new Operation(10, 15);
$operation2 = new Operation(5, 10);

$operations = collect([$operation1, $operation2]);

$kvit = new Kvit($operations);

$kvit->calculate(); // returns 200
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't test it, I don't have any example for that now, but maybe you can workaround on something like this. In the kvit model class create a method

```
public function self_amount()
{
   $sum = 0;
   if($this->operation()->exists()) // or count($this->operation)
     $operation = $this->operation->filter(function($item) use ($sum) {
        $sum += $item->amount * $item->price;
     });
   return $sum;
}
```

and in the blade just

```
<td>{{$data->self_amount()}}</td>
```